# Syncing email drafts in Windows Phone

Tags: email, sync

I am currently using HTC Radar, and I have used Android phone earlier, in the android phone, even the drafts are also synced for gmail (it is gmail app for android). In the HTC Radar, I dont see drafts being synced.

I used the out of the box email account from the Windows Phone. Is there any config change I need to do to enable this or this feature isn't available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested this a while back and this was what I observed.

Automatic synchronization only takes place with the Inbox. Any folders you have are not synchronized automatically. This will include your drafts folder.

To check if you have any new e-mails in any folder (including the draft folder), from the Windows Phone inbox options> tap `folders` > if required tap `show all folders` and tap the folder you need synchronized > tap the synchronize option to manually synchronize and receive e-mail updates for that folder.